# $G$ is a group of order 168 , $H$ <$G$ Proof that $[G:H]=m\geq 7$ using a morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

let $G$ be a simple group of order $168$.
Let $H$ be a subgroup such that $[G:H]=m, m>1$
Considering the action of $G$ on $G/H$ by $g.xH= (gx)H$

This operation is transitive so this implies a morphism between $G$ and Sm, the symmetric group of degree $m$.

Since $G$ is simple, the morphism is injective.

I don't understand the following sentence :
Hence the order of $G$ divides $m$.
That is possible if and only if $m \geq 7$

If someone can help me to understand why the order of $G$ divides $m$ ? ( i agree that since the morphism is injective the order of g has to be superior to the order of Sm= m!
but i don't see why it has to divides.

Comment: You surely mean "the order of $G$ divides $m!$".

Comment: yes that is the question i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the morphism
$$\phi : G \to S_m$$

Since this is injective $G$ is isomorphic to $\phi(G)$ and hence, they have the same cardinality.

Since $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $S_m$, by Lagrange Theorem, the order of $\phi(G)$ divides the order of $S_m$, which is $m!$.

Comment: i still don't understand why it is superior or equals to 7

Comment: $168$ does not divide $6!$ @FaroukDeutsch

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Indeed thank you

Comment: @FaroukDeutsch $168| m!$ if and only if $m \geq 7$.